# show how to add webservice assembly

Tags: c#, web-services, webservice-client

I'm new in c# and web services.

I can not use the classes that the web service offers me someone can help me or explain why it can not use, since I use the other services (identified in the image)

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/836/23770139.png/

http://imageshack.us/a/img818/5301/67546759.png

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean you can't use it? What happens? Can you reference the assembly? Can you use the fully qualified name?

Comment: i can't create object for this class, in my code don't recognize the name 

Teste.teste ex = new Teste();

Answer (score 0):

at the top of your c# code put `using`  then the name of the webservice , just like you would add any other namespace

ex.

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using net.virtualearth.dev;
```

I use virtualearth webservice for Bing's geolocate service, and this is how you include it it code ,

This is assuming you have already added the reference to it in your project, which I think you were trying to show a picture of , but you blacked out everything

EDIT:

To Add a webservice to c# project

Right Click Project   -> Add Service Reference

Click Advanced  then Enter URL , if there is a webservice found it will show up

Click Add Reference

Comment: Thanks for your reply, see the new image please and help me. http://imageshack.us/a/img818/5301/67546759.png

Comment: Thanks for your reply, see the new image please and help me. http://imageshack.us/a/img818/5301/67546759.png 

already tried what you said

Comment: did you try  'using Teste; '  or  'using Teste.UserTeste;'

Comment: I try these two ways and 'using Teste.Teste' and vs2010 don't recognize this

Comment: When you say webservice is it a wsdl file you are talking about?

Comment: I do not know very well, but I think I'm connectado services to alert a url.

Make sense?

Comment: but i think the webservice are in my project, because if aren't not show in windows object browser. I'm right?